# Reach/Router - authenticated vs. protected routes in main component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, reach-router

I'm trying to get a handle on why a logged-in user at the app root "/" doesn't get redirect to "/user/:uid" when that is specified as the path on the `<ProfilePage/>` component.

I should note, in my SignIn component I do that in the signIn callback, i.e. `` navigate(`/user/${uid}`); ``, but I can't make the path "/" redirect to "/user/:uid" (if logged in). I just get my NotFound.

```
function Application() {
  const user = useContext(UserContext);
  return user ? (
    <Router>
      <ProfilePage path={`/user/${user.uid}`} authenticatedUser={user} exact />
      <NotFound default />
    </Router>
  ) : (
    <Router>
      <SignIn path="/" />
      <SignUp path="signUp" />
      <PasswordReset path="passwordReset" />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Is this `react-router` or `reach-router` you have tagged it as both.

Comment: @JacobSmit reach-router. Sorry. I tagged react-router too because it has so many more users and I figured my problem is common to both.

Comment: I have not used `reach-router` but `react-router` makes use of a `Route` component for defining which routes go to which components / containers. In `reach-router` it appears to me that adding a path to any component nested directly under the `Router` component defines a route. A route is not a redirect, and `reach-router` appears to provide a separate component for this functionality, [Documentation](https://reach.tech/router/api/Redirect)